# Google VR Java and C++?

Tags: java, c++

I just saw the open source project on this in github (googlevr) and my question is how is it possible for C++ work with Java? I can understand that Java is for android stuff and C++ is for graphic, memory and tracking but how does two different compiled language work together?

Comment: [JNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface), for example.

Comment: JNA, JNR, Project Panama. I also recently watched a talk about adding handles for machine code snippets to be used by the jit.

Comment: what I saw was (  static {
    // Load our JNI code.
    System.loadLibrary("app_jni");
  })
but how does java compiler know how to compile the .cc code? dont you also need gcc?

Comment: Would you like to be a tester of my vr - java bridge?

Answer (score 3):

In C and C++ you can create shared libraries. They are handled a bit differently for each platform, but do roughly the same thing.

- Windows creates a .dll
- Mac creates a .dylib
- Linux creates a .so

These represent executable code that can be called by any process. This means that java code, matlab code, python code, etc can call code written in C/C++. Java uses a feature called JNI (Java Native Interface) to do this. JNI is notoriously tricky to setup and manage, so a lot of people use a library like Swig which essentially manages everything you need related to JNI in order to make calling precompiled C++ code from Java easier.

The key here is "precompiled". Someone, at some point, maybe even you, had to take the source code and compile it into a dll, dylib, or so and you have to have that shared library set up where the code that needs to use it (in this case your java app) can see it so that when the java app starts it can load the shared library and make calls into it.

For java one consideration is that java code is inherently cross-platform. C++ code needs to be compiled against each platform. So when you distribute your java app, you need to make sure you have a shared library available that is accessible for whichever platform it is being run on.